# IE's Content Advisor redirect issue

Tags: java, html, windows, internet-explorer, rdf

We have some clients that uses IE's Content Advisor and when they switch pages the login pop up appears this because we don't have a call for labels.rdf file on each one of our pages (we have more than 500 pages).

The problem is that Content Advisor tries to search the ICRA's RDF file on the current page but since we don't have this on each page, it tries to search on the same level as index.html file, and we did a change that if this kind of access in this path is made, we clear all user's info, which raises the login page again.

We've already tried to call from index.html file a newly created labels.rdf file just like this:

`<link rel="meta" href="http://www.example.org/corporate/labels.rdf" type="application/rdf+xml" />`

First we saw that we didn't had access to this RDF file.
But it was fixed.

Then, when testing this, we saw that it never reaches this labels.rdf file, showing the login page again.

Some one knows how Content Advisor works for a workaround here?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this? We are having same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for the solution, use secure cookies for session management. This worked for me.